# C++ am I correct about where each variable is stored?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Given this code:

```
void myFunction (int * a) {
    *a = 10;
}

int main () {
    int *b = new int;
    *b = 20;
    myFunction(b);
}
```

Am I right to think that both **a** and literal value **10** are stored in the **stack** (with **a** holding the memory address of the literal value 10)?

And also, is correct to say that **b** is stored in the stack while the value **20** is stored in the heap?

Thanks!

Comment: Literal values aren't stored in stack, they are copied there when the variables are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. `myFunction()` receives a pointer to a heap-allocated `int`. As such, while `a` is stored on the stack, the number 10 is stored in the heap.

Since both `a` and `b` are the same pointer, the same pointer would obviously be pointing to one place, at a time.

It's certainly possible for some other caller to invoke `myFunction()`, passing a pointer to some `int` variable that's declared in local scope and, as such, is stored on the stack. In that case, both `myFunction()`'s parameter, and what it's pointing to, will ultimately reside on the stack. But in this case, the pointer is pointing to an `int` instantiated in dynamic scope and, as such, is stored on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, C++ does not have a notion of the "stack". Instead the proper term would be "**storage duration**".

Objects with **automatic storage duration** are often reffered to as "stored on the stack", although this doesn't mean anything regarding the actual thread stack.

Instead automatic storage duration guarantees that the lifetime of your objects is bound to the scope they are defined in.

In your case you have two objects with automatic storage duration: `int *b`, defined in the scope of `main()`, and `int* a` in `myFunction`. Both of those are pointers to int;

The third object you have is an `int` created with the `new int` statement; it has **dynamic storage duration**, i.e. stored on the heap. Both `a` and `b` are used to modify its value.

Finally the literals are not stored at all. A literal is a fixed value, so it will be hard-coded into your binary. Again this doesn't mean the actual value is "stored" in the binary, instead the compiler just accounts for the effects of using that value, e.g.

```
a = 0;
```

can be compiled into

```
xor rax,rax
```

which doesn't explicitly mention 0.